# What does Cache-Control mean when a client uses it?

Tags: http, http-headers

I thought I understood what the Http Header "Cache-Control: max-age=3600" meant but then I came across it in a client request as this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means from a client's perspective.

Any insight would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Cache-Control attribute sent in request header (client to server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541077/why-is-cache-control-attribute-sent-in-request-header-client-to-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is explained here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4

When used by user agents, its aim is to get intermediate caches to revalidate the response - so it's not for the server to deal with.

In server responses, max-age tells the client (and intermediate caches) how long to cache the response for.

Comment: Is there any way we can force the clients not to revalidate for static assets?

Answer (score -3):

This means that the browser should NEVER cache the page, it should always retrieve a fresh copy of the page.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's because it only deals with the headers from the server and not the confusing client ones.

Comment: That's right, this question is specifically talking about when the Client sends that header.

Comment: This answer mistakes the Cache-Control on the Client with an the server, simply the wrong answer. Downvoted since this answer should have been deleted by the @Chi already