# Is GAE caching data when doing a http request through GAE?

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, servlets

When recieving a http post in GAE, I download a txt file from another server, do some parsing, and return the info. However, there seems to be a delay when I update this txt file and try to access it through GAE. Here's a step by step explanation:

1. I update a txt file on server A.
2. I verify that the txt file is updated by accessing the txt file on server A.
3. I notice a 5-10 min delay when accessing the same txt file through GAE(which fetches the txt from server A).

Maybe this the problem isn't GAE caching, but what else could it be?

Comment: Why don't you check the log to see if GAE downloads the file successfully? You could write the file's length/hash to log to check that new content is received.

Comment: I don't understand. I already know that GAE downloads the file successfully every time. It's just the wrong file. The file GAE downloads is lagging 5-10 minutes from the actual file. I confirmed this by downloading the file through my browser and comparing it to the file that I download through GAE.

Comment: @PeterKnego is suggesting you check the logs on the machine that's serving the file, to see if you're getting a request from App Engine, which will tell you if it's caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting [client cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966376/what-does-cache-control-mean-when-a-client-uses-it) in your GAE URL fetch code:

```
URL urlObj = new URL(url); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
urlObj.openConnection(); 
connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache,max-age=0"); 
connection.addRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

It seems to [work for some people](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/a8c8a6cb9fbe652f).